# Set a value when the column is null access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a table and *Name* column contains nulls.

```
   EID      Name            Desc
   1          DMK           Den (Obsolete)
   2                         Yes
   3          SFFSS         system force (Obsolete)
   4                         Yes
   5          BGRNK         BoardGMP
   6                         G (obsolete)
```

Some of the data in *Name* column is Null. How do i fill nulls with 'n/a' char using sql query?

Comment: Unfortunately this post is very unclear. It was closed as Duplicate, but it turns out the cited answer is for a different need. The worst thing is whichever way you interpret this post, learning the solution is best accomplished with either two minutes searching the Internet OR six minutes searching the built-in help. Not a real good fit for SO, in my humble opinion.  Down-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tableName
set tableName.Name = "n/a"
where tableName.Name IS NULL
```

You can run this SQL code with VBA like so:

```
Sub updateNULLS()

sSQL = "update tableName " _
        & "Set tableName.Name = 'n/a' " _
        & "where tableName.Name Is Null "

DoCmd.RunSQL (sSQL)

End Sub
```

If you want to simply query the column and want the query result to show `n/a` instead of `NULL`, you can build a query using the [Nz function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) like so:

```
select Nz(tablename.Name, 'n/a') from tableName
```

Comment: My understanding is that OP does not want to replace `null`s with `'N/A'`, he wants his query to return `'n/a'` for `null`s.

Comment: added to my answer to meet this need as well.

Comment: @ dasblinkenlight Set nulls with n/a.